# LINQ C# Sum and changing value to time (hh:mm:ss) in datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I created datatable using LINQ. I have int fields that represnts number. i want them to be shown as time (hh:mm:ss) . How can I do that ?

Here is my code :

```
var groupedData = from b in final.AsEnumerable()
                  orderby b.Field<string>("Agent")
                  group b by b.Field<string>("Agent") into g
                  select new
                  {
                      KeyName = g.Key,
                      Team = g.First().Field<string>("Team"),
                      Agent = g.First().Field<string>("Agent"),
                      TalkTime = g.Sum(b => b.Field < int ?> ("talkTime"))
                  };
```

The line in the code for that is :

```
 TalkTime = g.Sum(b => b.Field < int ?>
```

Comment: You have an int but want to treat it as timespan? What does `talkTime` represent, minutes or seconds?

Comment: `TimeSpan.From<something>`, where `<something>` depends on what unit `talkTime` is in.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get a `TimeSpan` from the `talkTime`-int, then use one of the [`TimeSpan.From...` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). So if these are for example seconds:

```
TalkTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime")))
```

with minutes:

```
TalkTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime")))
```

If you want to output a string you can use `TimeSpan.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")`:

```
TalkTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)g.Sum(b => b.Field<int?>("talkTime"))).ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim , Thats what I needed  (int) after the timespan ...!!

Comment: BTW - How can I show Hours as 136:00:00 ? I mean time time can be more then 24 hours...

Comment: Thanks Tim but using totalhours gives me 136.00 and i need to show it in hhh:mm:ss format